# Mips Assembly Language Error checking

Tags: mips

I have a program which takes an integer as input from the user (using syscall 5). when the user enters a special character ! @ # $ % ^ _ - ) ( instead of an integer it crashes, how can I fix the program to display an error message instead of crashing it?

this is the code I have written

```
    la $a0, prompt          # prompt the message ask for the answer n
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 5           # input the answer
syscall 

add $t1, $zero, $v0

                # store the answer in $t1

blt $t1, $s0, negative      # check for number entered < $s0
bgt $t1, $s1, exceed        # check for > $s1 number

la $a0, blank           # blank line
li $v0, 4
syscall
```

Sample Output :

```
This is a number guessing game between 0- 100. Let's begin.
Chances remains: 6
Enter your guess: 56

The secret number is higher than : 56
Chances remains: 5
Enter your guess: 67

The secret number is higher than : 67
Chances remains: 4
Enter your guess: 75

The secret number is lower than : 75
Chances remains: 3
Enter your guess: 74

The secret number is lower than : 74
Chances remains: 2
Enter your guess: 72

The secret number is lower than : 72
Chances remains: 1
Enter your guess: 70

The secret number is lower than : 70
Chances remains: 0
Sorry...You lost.
The secret number is: 69
Do you want to play again?
1.Yes 
2.No 
Choice: 2
Your average guess: 3
-- program is finished running --
```

Comment: Perhaps there's a better way to go about whatever you're trying to do. Can you clarify?

Comment: The code above is actually part of a number guessing game, the program chooses a random number (using syscall 42)and the user enters his guess. The user has 6 chances to guess the correct answer.

Comment: This is a number guessing game between 0- 100. 
Chances remains: 6
Enter your guess: 56

The secret number is higher than : 56
Chances remains: 5
Enter your guess: 67

The secret number is higher than : 67
Chances remains: 4
Enter your guess: 75

The secret number is lower than : 75
Chances remains: 3
Enter your guess: 74

The secret number is lower than : 74
Chances remains: 2
Enter your guess: 72

The secret number is lower than : 72
Chances remains: 1
Enter your guess: 70

The secret number is lower than : 70
Chances remains: 0
Sorry...You lost.
The secret number is: 69

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop it from crashing. It will always try to parse an integer from the input. You can display an error message and recover using an exception handler.

[MARS exception handling](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/MarsExceptions.html)

**Update:**

> The code above is actually part of a number guessing game, the program
>   chooses a random number (using syscall 42)and the user enters his
>   guess. The user has 6 chances to guess the correct answer.

An alternative to writing a handler is to read the user input into a buffer with `read_char` or `read_string` and performing the extraction yourself. Using `read_char` requires you to accept characters up to a new line.

As you iterate over the buffer, ensure each character's value is between 48 and 57 (see ASCII chart). If the value is out of range, display an error. Otherwise, subtract that value from 48 to get the digit, multiply the digit by the ten's place, and add it to the accumulated sum. I recommend iterating over the buffer backwards so that calculating the ten's place is simple.

Pseudocode for the algorithm can be found in this [Casting in MIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265639/casting-in-mips/10266085#10266085) topic.

Comment: yes but im not sure how to code an exception handler, and my text book doesnt cover that part well. I would appreciate it, if u could give me a brief idea on how to do it, or even refer me to some websites that have documentation on Exceptions.

Comment: @DaffyDaffy: Did you look at the link in my answer?

Comment: ooops sorry completely looked over that, Thanks will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

MIPS assembly code for angle unit conversion (radians to degrees and gradians)

```
.data
angle_prompt:   .asciiz "Enter the angle in radians: "
degree_result:  .asciiz "Angle in degrees: "
gradian_result: .asciiz "Angle in gradians: "

.text
main:
    # Prompt for user input
    li $v0, 4           # System call for print_str
    la $a0, angle_prompt
    syscall

    # Read the input angle from the user
    li $v0, 7           # System call for read_float
    syscall
    mov.s $f12, $f0     # Move the input angle to $f12

    # Convert radians to degrees
    l.s $f0, $f12       # Load the input angle to $f0
    mul.s $f1, $f0, 180 # Multiply by 180
    div.s $f2, $f1, 3.14159 # Divide by pi
    mov.s $f12, $f2     # Move the result to $f12

    # Display the result in degrees
    li $v0, 4           # System call for print_str
    la $a0, degree_result
    syscall

    li $v0, 2           # System call for print_float
    syscall

    # Convert radians to gradians
    l.s $f0, $f12       # Load the result in degrees to $f0
    mul.s $f1, $f0, 10  # Multiply by 10/9 to convert to gradians
    mov.s $f12, $f1     # Move the result to $f12

    # Display the result in gradians
    li $v0, 4           # System call for print_str
    la $a0, gradian_result
    syscall

    li $v0, 2           # System call for print_float
    syscall

    # Exit the program
    li $v0, 10          # System call for exit
    syscall
```